# For loop is going out of range

Tags: vb.net

I'm processing a for loop but it goes out of index range and I can't understand why. Here is the code I'm using:

```
Dim t As Integer = CInt(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
Dim wi As New List(Of Double)()
Dim hi As New List(Of Double)()
Dim zi As New List(Of Double)()
Dim avx As New List(Of Double)()
Dim ziarray As New List(Of Double)()
Dim avihi As Double
Dim avsum As Double
For i = 0 To t
    wi.Add(CInt(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("w").Value))
    hi.Add(CInt(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("h").Value))
    zi.Add(CInt(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("z").Value))
    avx(i) = wi(i) * hi(i)
    avsum = CDbl(avsum + avx(i))
    avihi = CDbl(avihi + (avx(i) * hi(i)))
    ziarray(i) = hi(i) + zi(i)
Next
```

In particular, I receive the error for the avx(i) line inside the loop.

---

Edited my code as follows but always getting the same error:

```
    Dim t As Integer = CInt(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
    Dim wi As New List(Of Double)()
    Dim hi As New List(Of Double)()
    Dim zi As New List(Of Double)()
    Dim avx As New List(Of Double)()
    Dim ziarray As New List(Of Double)()
    Dim avihi As Double
    Dim avsum As Double
    For i = 0 To t
        wi.Add(CInt(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("w").Value))
        hi.Add(CInt(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("h").Value))
        zi.Add(CInt(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("z").Value))
    Next
For i = 0 to t 
        avx(i) = wi(i) * hi(i)
        avsum = CDbl(avsum + avx(i))
        avihi = CDbl(avihi + (avx(i) * hi(i)))
        ziarray(i) = hi(i) + zi(i)
    Next
```

Comment: You're trying to access an element in `avx` before adding any elements to it. On a related note, try to use more meaningful variable names. It makes it easier to spot mistakes like this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited my post trying to follow your comment but I'm getting back the same error.

Comment: @telemaco10399 You forgot to tell us which line it fails on and the values of the relevant variables.

Comment: How are you feeding your DataGridView ? If the data comes from a dataset or datatable, this is the source you should be using for your calculations, instead of reading from the UI control. Seems to me that using LINQ would be beneficial. As said above, the poor choice of variable names makes the code rather obscure but there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a list is initialized:

```
New List(Of Double)()
```

It has no elements, it is empty.  So you can't access any elements in it.  But the first thing you do with your `avx` list is try to access an element:

```
avx(i) = wi(i) * hi(i)
```

Regardless of the value of `i`, this will fail because the list has no elements.

You already know how to add an element to a list, for example here you add an element to the `wi` list:

```
wi.Add(CInt(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("w").Value))
```

If you want your `avx` list to have any elements, you need to add some.

Comment: I was writing avx as an array and not as a list. Here is the mistake. Now is working fine.